# Why does PWD variable point to home directory in a file?

Tags: c, linux, file, path

I have a header file in which I have a function load_files() which should copy a specific file from project directory into some path in user's computer. The problem is I can't locate the file in my project directory, I can't even locate the project directory.
Here is my code.

```
void load_database_files(const char * prog_dir) {
  char cmd[100];
  const char * proj_path = getenv("PWD");
  sprintf(cmd, "cp -r %s%s %s", proj_path, "/src/database/warehouse.db", prog_dir);
  system(cmd);
  exit(1);
}
```

I would expect PWD to point to the project directory, from where I could locate the file, but instead it returns the path of $HOME. How can I work around this? I am using gnome-builder IDE. If there is any other relevant info I need to provide please let me know.

Comment: _I have a header file load_files()_ , `load_files()` looking at the style used is called a function in `C` or `C++` and in many  programming languages

Comment: on lighter note, better to print `cmd` , before using in `system(cmd);` ,  to be sure that we are calling correct.

Comment: Ah sorry I fixed that ). Yes I should probably do that for proper debugging.

Comment: You should also be using `snprintf()` (And checking for cases where the final string would be too long to hold in `cmd`) instead of `sprintf()`.

Comment: @Shawn Yes I was planning to change that later on. Any ideas how I can work around the PWD issue?

Comment: Are you setting the environment variable PWD to the project directory before running your program? Usually your shell sets it to whatever the current working directory is when the program is started; I'd use a different name.

Comment: I have not set that. But shouldn't the current working directory be the directory of the .h file the function is written in? I'm using PWD to acquire wherever the project is installed in the user's computer. If I new the path before hand I wouldn't need to use PWD. That means I can't really set the variable to anything else before hand as it begs the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read shell documentation.  `PWD` is an environment variable where the shell stores its current directory's path.  So, if you are at home (let's say it is `/home/user1`) and chdir to `$HOME/projects/project_a`, the shell will store `/home/user1/projects/project_a` in variable `PWD`.  The shell updates this variable always that you execute the internal shell command `cd`, so you have two
alternatives:

- Use a different variable name for your project directory.  Let's say your project is named `babilony`, and it is located in `$HOME/projects`.  A good name would be to use an environment variable like `BABILONY_HOME`, and initialize it in your `.profile` with a line like

```
export BABILONY_HOME="$HOME/projects/babilony"
```

and then use the following secuence:

```
void load_database_files(const char * prog_dir) {
  char cmd[100];
  const char * proj_path = getenv("BABILONY_HOME"); /* this will point to your project's base directory */
  sprintf(cmd, "cp -r %s%s %s", proj_path, "/src/database/warehouse.db", prog_dir);
  /* this would expand to 'cp -r /home/user1/projects/babilony/src/database/warehouse.db <prog_dir>' */
  system(cmd);
  exit(1);
}
```

but don't use the `PWD` variable as it changes everytime you move around over the filesystem.